# Jquery is not working?

Tags: jquery

My question is related to jquery. I have attached jquery using google hosted libraries to my page but it seems it is not working and I am not able to use draggable function.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Learning jQuery</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
        libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    #square {
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
      background-color: grey;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="square"></div>
  <script>
    $("#square").draggable();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does `jquery.min.js` exist in your directory? Any errors in your console?

Comment: Try to add jquery.min.js the same way you added jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

It's better to wait untill the document is fully loaded.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#square').draggable();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There you are,

You had badly referenced `jquery` and `jquery-ui`
(Your referenced version of jQuery Ui does not have the `draggable` component)

There are correct cdn url for:
jQuery:
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js
jQuery Ui:
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js

In addition of that, if you don't know where to find your CDN Hosted scripts, there is a good library refering many of available librairies:

[**CDN JS**](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/)

**Your working snippet:**

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Learning jQuery</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>

<script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <style>
    #square {
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
      background-color: grey;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="square"></div>
  <script>
    $("#square").draggable();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```